# Current across high speed mechanical switch contact even if it can’t be measured?

Tags: current, amplifier, switches, dc

If I am cycling a mechanical switch at a frequency higher than the bandwidth of a current amplifier and biased using a DC source, is current actually flowing across the contact? The following describes the scenario in more detail.

I am performing contact reliability tests on piezoelectric micromechanical switches to observe degradation of the electrical interfaces after millions of hot-switched contact cycles. I use a home-built logarithmic current amplifier to detect current, which allows me to track contact resistance as a function of cycles. This works beautifully if I am actuating the switch slowly – up to tens of Hz. However, I would like to speed up the actuation frequency of the switch beyond the bandwidth (kHz) of the current amplifier. I have tried high frequency cycling and, unsurprisingly, did not detect any current across the source and drain of the switch using the logarithmic amplifier. Does this mean that [A] no (or potentially some fraction of) current is flowing across the contact or [B] current is flowing across the contact but I just can’t detect it given the bandwidth of the amplifier?

My signal chain is: Instrumentation controller with DC source → BNC cable → logarithmic current amplifier → wire to switch → mechanical switch with metal electrical contacts → wire to ground

Actuation of the mechanical switch is achieved with a separate signal generator and isolated from the source, drain, and source-drain leads of the switch.

I am just so confused with the electrical theory behind current/DC voltage in this scenario. I’m not sure if this would be characterized as an AC or DC phenomena. If AC, it seems that no (or some) current might be flowing across the contact and that I would need to calculate the effect of the impedance and inductance of the instrumentation controller, BNC, log IV amplifier, and switch contact to estimate current flow during a switching event. Or, I may be overcomplicating things and it’s as simple as the current is flowing (i.e. it is hot-switching) but I just can’t see it.

Overall, I want to hot-switch at high frequency and can slow down actuation periodically to measure current/contact resistance with high fidelity. Thus, I am not looking for a method to accurately measure current at high speed, but want to know if current would be flowing even if not observed.

Thank you for any perspective you can provide. This question has been keeping me up for weeks and the electrical engineers I have spoken with in person haven’t been confident of their answers.

Comment: I think the first step would be to get an oscilloscope and actually observe what's happening first. Also, you say "DC source", which implies it's a **current source**. Most people actually mean **constant voltage source** here – is it really a current source?

Comment: Please share some diagram/schematics. I believe that before trying to figure out a way to explain the behavior you're observing you need to understand a little more of the actual phenomenon that is opening and closing the switch. How does the resistence can be seen over time during the switch actuation? How does it reflect the current over time that your amplifier get excited?

Comment: Current probes exist with bandwidth from DC to 50 MHz or more. They are not cheap, but maybe you can rent.

Comment: Marcus - I did mean "constant voltage source". I apologize that I am mincing terms here. Being a mechanical engineer, I'm a bit of a fish out of water here. Thank you! When you say get an oscilloscope and observe what's happening, what do you mean? I have a feeling that an oscilloscope won't provide much insight as the currents (and corresponding voltage drops) are pretty low, in the nA range.

Comment: mkeith - Thank you for your response. There is a bit more detail in the experimental setup - some of it involving custom experimental chambers - that has been left out of the picture for clarity. These constraints do not impact the electrical signal chain. However, due to cost constraints and geometric limitations of the experimental setup, I had to create my own log IV amplifier. I did look into high frequency current probes, but the cost and geometry of the devices would not work for the experiment.

Comment: PDuarte - I'll work on a schematic tonight. Thank you for reading my question and providing feedback!

Comment: I can't believe it would be cheaper to pay someone to design a current probe than to rent or buy one.

Comment: nanoamperes? Really? Wow! how do you cool down your apparatus to take the measurements, and how do you shield from radiation?

Comment: @DimwittedAndAmazed when you add that schematic, make sure to also give some rough numbers on voltages and currents involved – that makes a big design difference, here!